# aws s3 write permissions - access deined

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i wrote an s3 policy using the json generator

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

i do manage to login to the bucket not to write
what is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to give write permission to the objects of the bucket. The list bucket permission should be given to the bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::XXXXX/*", "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXX"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current policy applies only to the bucket. For objects you need `/*` after the bucket name:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXX", 
                "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXX/*"
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`ListBucket` and `GetBucketLocation` apply to bucket, thus you also need bucket arn (i.e. without `/*`).